# In R, how can I join data by similar, but not identical, centroid (or numeric argument)?

Tags: r, join

I'm building a transition matrix of land use change (state) over the years.

I'm therefore comparing shapefile years after years and build a dataframe with:

Landuse year1 - Landuse year2 - ....- ID- centroid

with the following function :

```
full_join(landuse1, landuse2, by="centroid")
```

where centroid is the actual centroid of the polygons. A centroid, is basically a vector of two numeric value.

However, the centroid, year after year, can slitghly shift (because the polygon actually change a little bit) leading in incomplete data gathering through the `full_join` function because centroid must exactly match.

I'd like to include a "more or less" argument, so that that any centroid close enough to the one from the year before can be joined to the datagrame for that particular polygon.
**But I'm not sure how ?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

So the general term for what you are trying to do is called fuzzy matching. Im not sure how exactly it would work for the coordinates of a centroid. My Idea would be to calculate the distance between the Coordinates, and then set a margin of error, say 0.5%, and if they deviate from each other by less than that you could declare it a match. Basically loop through your list of locations and give the matches some unique ID, which you can then use for the join

Comment: Thank you Sven for your answer. That will however take forever... I have   1 812 000 polygons to loop through.. Isn't there a built-in function of fuzzy join ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590119/fuzzy-matching-of-coordinates
I found another post talking about a similar topic. I think calculating the distances between some coordinates should be quite a quick calculation even for a large dataset like the one you have. Then calculating the deviation as a % should also not take long computationally since its a linear operation